# No display during bios

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios

I am facing a display problem in my HP laptop.

I left it on overnight and it's battery got drained.

Now when i start it up, it screen remain black until ububtu boots up. Ubuntu is working fine and display is good.
So, **basically it is black screen during bios and grub** and everything else is working fine.

Bios and grub is working but nothing is coming on screen. All black.
No error in syslog.

Did anyone has an idea about this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to acess uefi setup by

```
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

I wrote try because it is not on every system possible.

[source](http://systemctl%20reboot%20--firmware-setup)